# Visual studio how to change where the using statements appear for class template

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio, C# whenever I create a new class the using statements always appear above the namespace.  How do I change this so that they appear within the namespace by default?

Comment: You can do this with Resharper if you have access to a license/feel like buying one